# How does openvswitch interrupt packet?

Tags: openvswitch

I found that the interrupt handler of the ixgbe driver isn't called when the interface is registered as port in openvswitch.

Then, how does openvswitch interrupt packet?

Thanks

Comment: How did you check that?

Comment: @pchaigno Thanks. I add a printk function at interrupt handler.

Comment: As far as I know, unless you're using Open vSwitch-DPDK, Open vSwitch receives packets through the traditional Linux networking stack (for the interrupt part at least). So there seems to be an error in the way you checked that. Could you add more details in your original post on how/where you added the printk call?